# Some Toolbar Buttons are missing in Froala wysiwyg Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, froala

Full Froala wysiwyg Editor looks like this:
[image]

But after adding the API in my project, Some of the Toolbar buttons are missing. The snap is shown below.

[image]

As seen from the above, most of the toolbar buttons are missing from my editor, like- color, paragraph formatting etc.

I have included the following libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.7.1/css/froala_editor.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.7.1/css/froala_style.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.7.1/js/froala_editor.min.js'></script>
```

And using the following setting for editor:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {$('.editable-question').froalaEditor({
            initOnClick: true,
              charCounterCount: false,
        });
        });
    </script>
```

I have tried explicitly mentioning `toolbarButtons` array, also tried `toolbarButtonsXS`, `toolbarButtonsMD` etc for screen size option. Still no result.
What am I missing?

Update:
Using `$('.editable-question').froalaEditor();` only has the same result.

Comment: Please post code defining button array.  Do you want buttons that need separate plugins?

Comment: @Seano666 , for example if I add `toolbarButtons=['bold', 'underline', 'color', 'formatOL', 'formatUL']`
only bold and underline buttons appear. But, color and bullet buttons are missing. Its not that, their icon is missing the button altogether is missing.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you think should be happening and what actually happens?

Comment: For FormatOL and FormatUL, did you add the Lists plugin as outlined here?  https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#toolbarButtons

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, edited the post

Comment: @Seano666 you are right, I missed that part. Thank you. Can you help me finding a clean way of adding all the js files from a folder? Or I must add them individually with script tags. I am using SpringBoot, Thymeleaf bdw.

Comment: You should probably add them all separately with script tags.  There's not a really good way to do it cleaner.  I'll add an answer since it looks like I've answered your original question.

Comment: If I helped you with your initial question, would you mind marking my answer as the accepted answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some buttons for the Froala editor require separate plugins, for which the files must be included manually.

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#toolbarButtons

```
<script src="../js/plugins/lists.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this is angular, it wasn't working for me by including the plugin JS in the angular.json file. Sticking it at the top of the main.ts file like so:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import 'hammerjs';
import 'froala-editor/js/plugins/fullscreen.min.js';
import 'froala-editor/js/plugins/code_view.min.js';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}

const providers = [
  { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] }
];

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Worked for me.